# Need guide for writing function to resolve root data type with nested sub type

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I have mock data and GraphQL server setup as shown below

Please guide how to write resolver function with sub type e.g. data kept in JSON (database) as customerId but i want data to be return as Customer type

Thanks

#### Mock Order Type JSON Data

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "customerId": 145,
        "productIds": [
            136,
            148,
            102
        ]
    }
]
```

#### GraphQL Server

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const graphQLHTTP = require('express-graphql')
const { buildSchema } = require('graphql')

const db = require('./db.json')
const app = express()

const schema = buildSchema(`
    type Customer {
        id: Int
        firstName: String
        lastName: String
    }

    type Product {
        id: Int
        productName: String
    }

    type Order {
        id: Int
        customer: Customer
        products: [Product]
    }

    type Query {
        orders: [Order]
    }
`)

const resolver = {
    orders() {
        return db['orders']
            .map(order => {
                const customer = db['customers'].find(c => c.id == order.customerId)

                const products = order.productIds
                    .map(id => db['products'].find(p => p.id == id))

                return { ...order, customer, products }
            })
    }
}

app.use(graphQLHTTP({
    schema,
    rootValue: resolver,
    graphiql: true
}))

app.listen(3000)
```